# Django Tutorial - Problem with Laptop Django when running "python manage.py xyz" -> AttributeError: 'Choice' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following the Coursera Course on Django as well as the Django tutorial. The Coursera course runs on Pythonanwhere. Now I came up with idea to run it on my MacAir.
Thus I created a Conda environment and followed all the steps as for Pythonanywhere.
But whenever I run anything like "python manage.py ...." I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Choices' object has no attribute 'model'

edit:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in  main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/sitepackages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute().
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 395, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 64, in handle fail_level=getattr(checks, options['fail_level']),
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 53, in check_admin_app errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 82, in check if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
**AttributeError: 'Choice' object has no attribute 'model'**

After researching I finally went from file to file and made a copy paste (except one or two). I even downgraded my Python version from 3.8 to 3.6.3. Didn't help.

I checked for typos and finally did copy-paste. Nothin' :-(

And this my polls/model.py:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

edit 2:
polls/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Question, Choice

admin.site.register(Question, Choice)
```

In the meantime I changed the name "Choice" to "Choices" just to get the error message:

> AttributeError: 'Choices' object has no attribute 'model'

I am quite sure that it is a simple error but I cannot find the solution :-(

Thanks.

Comment: Add the *full* traceback.

Comment: The problem is the `ModelAdmin` you defined for `Choice`.

Comment: I added the polls/admin.py file/content. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in an [**`.register(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.register) is an optional `ModelAdmin`, not an extra model. If you want to add extra ones, you make extra calls to `.register(…)`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Question, Choice

admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your models.py and forms.py but I think you wrote model instead of models in forms.py or models.py. I mean

Choices(models.Model)--> you wrote I guess model.Model

Comment: Thanks. But no. I did write Choice(models.Model). Have a look at the post. The polls/model.py as well as the polls/admin.py are in it.